# Can openiddict have equivalent features of AWS Cognito like: User pool, App ID and Custom claims

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant, abp, openiddict

I would like to find out if openiddict (https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) and
Amazon Cognito.
I plan to use ABP OpenIddict Module (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/6.0/Modules/OpenIddict
which provides advanced authentication features like single sign-on, single log-out, and API access control. This module persists applications, scopes, and other OpenIddict-related objects to the database.

In this video at the time mark: Amazon EKS SaaS deep dive: A multi-tenant EKS SaaS solution
https://youtu.be/tXVLjWjEEwo?t=1250
You can see the onboarding experience when a SaaS tenant selects to provision its infrastructure and application using EKS Kubernetes.

Amazon Cognito creates User pool, App ID and Custom claims for the tenant.
Can OpenIddict have equivalent functionality?

I would like to rebuild AWS SaaS provisioning with DigitalOcean kubernetes and abp.io framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Yes, you could implement a similar solution.

Long anser:
Abp is an opinionated framework with a lot of best practices pre implemented for you. You need to understand how ABP does things in the first place to understand how to extend it. For selfservice onboarding you have to create your own registration process, which in turn would create a user and tenant.

Also openiddic is for all intents and purposes already implemented. Creating a selfservice onboarding would probably only touch the Account Module, the Tenant Management Module and the Identity Module

Read the doc on the abp site:

```
[https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Account][1]
[https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Tenant-Management][2]
[https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Identity][3]
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph. My thinking is to have a separate app and db for on-boarding tenants and their admins and synchronize tenant and admin information across to a specific SaaS app provisioned in a specific Kubernetes cluster where a tenant admin will login and manage its tenant settings and users and that tenant can use shared db or has its own db based on pricing tier settings. There is a problem of how to provision a db because abp.io creates db based on connection string, while in kubernetes has its own mechanics of how to provision a db instance which might or not live in particular sql seever